# Как использовать predicate в jpa query

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

Когда вставляю Predicate в jpa query, то он его не сортирует по критериям

```
@Query("SELECT SUM (u.sum) from User u")
Double getSums(Predicate predicate);
```

Comment: Предикат навряд ли будет что-то сортировать. Предикаты, как `выражения, использующие одну или более величину с результатом булева типа`, используются для фильтрации, для `where`.

Comment: Просто у меня получилось один раз вытащить одну колонку таким образом, но потом что сделал и теперь он просто игнорирует этот predicate и при этом не выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сортировки не предикат передается, а объект типа Pageable (заодно и ограничение можно выставить на количество получаемых).

[Здесь](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting) хороший туториал по Pageable

Для фильтрации ответов попробуйте использовать статический метод where в месте, где вы вызываете вашу функцию:

```
yourRepositoryName.getSums(where(hasSomeProperty()));
```

Да, в этом случае вы можете убрать из сигнатуры метода в репозитории передачу параметра "Predicate predicate".

**UPD1:**

Передавать аргументом функции where необходимо специальный предикат - класс Specification, параметризированный искомой для репозитория сущностью. Хороший пример описан [здесь](https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification).